# Local extrema of $x^3+y^2+6y$

Tags: calculus, optimization, partial-derivative

I have to find local extrema of $x^3+y^2+6y$.

I found out that the stationary points are $(0,-3)$. I also found the Hess matrix for this function and computed the determinant, which is $12x$. But now I am stuck and I don't know how to continue and find out whether It's the local minimum or local maximum. Thanks for your advices.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: You have to asses the definitness of your Hessian in $(0,-3)$, by finding its eigenvalues.